# MySQL error #1215: Cannot add Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to implement the tables shown in the picture:
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHwJu.png)
(database scheme taken from http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/recipes/index.htm).

But I'm having problems with the Recipe_step_ingredients table. When adding foreign key constraints, I get error #1215 for the recipe_steps_id constraint (when not adding that constraint, I don't get the error and I can add the other two constraints).

Here is may command for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE recipe_step_ingredients (
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    step_number INTEGER,
    ingredient_id INTEGER,
    amount_required VARCHAR(128),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES recipe_steps (recipe_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (step_number) REFERENCES recipe_steps (step_number) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredients (ingredient_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, step_number, ingredient_id)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Anybody knows what could be the problem with it?

EDIT: Changed the code to match the naming conventions in the picture.
Also, here is the rest of the DDL I used:

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
    recipe_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    recipe_name VARCHAR(128),
    recipe_description VARCHAR(4096),
    
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id),
    INDEX (recipe_name)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB

CREATE TABLE recipe_steps (
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    step_number INTEGER,
    instructions VARCHAR(4096),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES recipes (recipe_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, step_number)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB

CREATE TABLE ingredient_types (
    ingredient_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ingredient_type_description VARCHAR(4096),
    
    PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_type_id)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB

ALTER TABLE ingredient_types ADD COLUMN ingredient_type_name VARCHAR(128);
ALTER TABLE ingredient_types ADD INDEX(ingredient_type_name);

CREATE TABLE ingredients (
    ingredient_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ingredient_type_id INTEGER,
    ingredient_name VARCHAR(128),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_type_id) REFERENCES ingredient_types (ingredient_type_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id),
    INDEX (ingredient_name)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB

CREATE TABLE recipe_step_ingredients (
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    step_number INTEGER,
    ingredient_id INTEGER,
    amount_required VARCHAR(128),
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES recipe_steps (recipe_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (step_number) REFERENCES recipe_steps (step_number) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredients (ingredient_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, step_number, ingredient_id)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Comment: What is the DDL of referenced tables?

Comment: Show the code for how you create the recipe_steps table. You aren't following the naming convention in the picture so we have no idea what your recipe_steps table looks like

Comment: share complete DDL of both tables.

Comment: use     recipe_steps_id **INT** instead of  recipe_steps_id **INTEGER** and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that:

- the foreign key references ALL the attributes of the key of the referenced relation (you cannot reference only some of them). SO if the key of R is (A,B), you should reference both A and B. You cannot reference only A or only B.
- the attribute(s) you are referencing in a foreign key constraint is defined as UNIQUE or is the Primary key of the relation. In Mysql this can also be done by defining the attribute a KEY or UNIQUE KEY.
- If you are referencing the primary key you don't need to indicate the name of the attribute after the table (the default is its primary key).

In your case,

- make sure that the table recipe_steps has an attribute recipe_steps_id, and
- this attribute is either UNIQUE KEY, KEY or the primary key of the relation
- Also, make sure the corresponding index (for the key) has been created.

Comment: Tried to make so that in table recipe_steps, the column recipe_steps_id (called step_number in the picture) was an autoincrement, but it seems InnoDB can't handle an autoincrement as part of a composite key, so I had to set it to be a regular integer. Maybe the solution would be to use recipe_steps_id as an autoincrement and the only PRIMARY KEY, and not include the recipe_id in the composite key.

Comment: It must the ENTIRE key.  It cannot reference only one attribute of a multi-attribute key. If your key is (A,B), the foreign key must be (D,E) references R(A,B). It cannot be (D) references R(A)

Comment: This was indeed the problem, thanks for your help